# How to pushd mutliple folders on Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I include multiple paths?
Like for example:

```
pushd C:\Users\Downloads\back\dotNet 
      C:\Users\Downloads\back\MySQL
```

And exclude every file with extension .log

```
7za.exe a -tzip -mx5 -x!\*.log* "C:\Users\Desktop\Downloadbak-%TODAY%.zip"
popd


ECHO.

PAUSE
```

Comment: `for %%a in (C:\Users\Downloads\back\dotNet 
..\MySQL) do pushd "%%a"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually 2 questions here:

- *pushd*
- *7z(a).exe*

Regarding *pushd*: a simple answer to your question is: **It can't be done**. 
*pushd* (push directory) and *popd* (pop directory) operate on a stack like structure - operations on a stack are *push* and *pop*

- *push* has an argument and inserts it over the current stack top (the last element inserted), if any, and thus that becomes the stack top
- *pop* simply takes the top of the stack out and making the next element of the stack (if any) its top

So:

- *pushd* inserts the current *dir* (*%CD%*) on the top of an internal stack and changes the current directory to the directory that it got as an argument
- *popd* changes the current directory to the top of the (same) internal stack and also removes it from the stack

But your desired behavior can be achieved by a sequence of *pushd* / *popd* commands, and there is one aspect that needs to be clear: *pushd* and *popd* commands order is reversed - explanation below:

Let's assume that the internal stack is empty: you're located in *${DIR1}* (this is a directory **full path** somewhere in your filesystem). As a note, *Nix* style variables (*${...}*) are just (directory) placeholders:

- You execute:

  ```bat
  pushd ${DIR1}
  ```
- This inserted *${DIR1}* in the stack and changed your current *dir* to *${DIR2}* (this is where you are located). Then you execute:

  ```bat
  pushd ${DIR3}
  ```
- This inserted *${DIR2}* on the stack (on top of *${DIR1}*) and changed the current *dir* to *${DIR3}* (this is where you are located). Now, you do your operations, and want to get back, so you execute:

  ```bat
  popd
  ```
- This takes out *${DIR2}* (the last one that was *pushd*ed) from the stack and changes the current directory to it (you will be located in *${DIR2}*). And finally when executing again:

  ```bat
  popd
  ```
- *${DIR1}* is being removed from the stack (and thus the stack becomes empty - as it was at the beginning) and it changes the current directory to it, so you will be located in *${DIR1}* just like before the 1<sup>st</sup> *pushd* command

Now, regarding the *7zip* executable (I see that you typed *7z **a**.exe*, while on my computer is *7z.exe* (just installed it)):

It seems that your filter is perfectly fine, but it only strips the log files from he current directory, the sub directories seem to ignore the *-x* flag. So, I tested and it turns out that if I pass *-r* (recursive) it will also strip out all the *.log* files from sub-directories (although I can't explain why your pattern doesn't work with directories - maybe it only refers to base file names?).

Here's the command (notice that I removed the ***\*** before the *******):

```bat
7z.exe a -tzip -mx5 -r -x!*.log somefile.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can't.

`pushd` **changes the current directory** to the directory you supply and before changing the directory it saves the current one on the stack.

But there can only be a single "current" directory thus it does not make sense (nor could it work) to supply more than one directory to the `pushd` command.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the scene but here goes anyways. Below is an implementation of a stack data structure in Windows batch scripting.

**Features:**

- You must call the **:InitializeStack** subroutine before using the stack.
- Push items on the stack by calling the **:Push** subroutine.
- Pop items off the stack by calling the **:Pop** subroutine.
- The variable **$Count** will always contain the count of items in the stack.
- The variable **$Top** will always contain the most recent item added to the stack.
- The variable **$Bottom** will always contain the first item added to the stack.
- You can dump the content of the stack by calling the **:DumpStack** subroutine.
- The type of items that you can push on the stack is anything that can be stored in a variable. For example, **Call :Push "String 1"**, **Call :Push "%1"**, **Call :Push "%MyVariable%"**, etc.

I use the stack in my batch files to keep track of subroutine calls. Every subroutine in my batch files starts with **Call :Push %0**, which pushes the current subroutine's name onto the stack and ends with **Call :Pop**.

Some may find it an over-kill for batch scripting but I enjoyed creating it and I hope someone will find this useful, **enjoy**.

```
@Echo Off
Cls
SetLocal
SetLocal EnableExtensions
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Call :InitializeStack

Call :Push "String 1"
Call :Push "String 2"
Call :Push "String 3"
Call :Pop

Echo Total items in stack = !$Count!
Echo Top of stack         = !$Top!
Echo Bottom of stack      = !$Bottom!
Call :DumpStack

Goto End

:InitializeStack
:------------------------------------------------------------
Set "$Stack[0]=0"
Set "$Count=!$Stack[0]!"
Set "$Top="
Set "$Bottom="
Exit /b

:DumpStack
:------------------------------------------------------------
If !$Stack[0]! EQU 0 (
  Echo Stack is empty.
) Else (
  Echo.
  Echo Stack Dump
  Echo ----------
  For /l %%a In (!$Stack[0]!,-1,1) Do (Echo !$Stack[%%a]!)
)
Exit /b

:Push <String>
:------------------------------------------------------------
Set /a "$Stack[0]+=1"
Set "$Count=!$Stack[0]!"
Set "$Top=%~1"
Set "$Bottom=!$Stack[1]!"
Set "$Stack[!$Stack[0]!]=!$Top!"
Exit /b

:Pop
:------------------------------------------------------------
If !$Stack[0]! EQU 0 (
  Echo "Stack is empty."
) Else (
  Set "$Stack[!$Stack[0]!]="
  Set /a "$Stack[0]-=1"
  Set "$Count=!$Stack[0]!"
  If !$Stack[0]! GTR 0 (
    For %%a In (!$Stack[0]!) Do Set "$Top=!$Stack[%%a]!"
    Set "$Bottom=!$Stack[1]!"
  ) Else (
    Set "$Top="
    Set "$Bottom="
  )
)Exit /b

:End
```

To place all your paths on the stack, use the following command:

```
For %%a In ("<path1>" "<path2>") Do Call :Push "%%~a"
```

To carry out an action on the items on the stack, you can use:

```
For /l %%a In (!$Stack[0]!,-1,1) Do (pushd !$Stack[%%a]!)
```